# select every x elements of a list in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops

I have a list that can have 5,10,15,... elements.
I would like to iterate on it every 5 elements to build my object.
For example :

```
var o1=new MyObject(list[0],list[1],list[2],list[3],list[4])
var o2=new MyObject(list[5],list[6],list[7],list[8],list[9])
```

How can I build a "for" loop to iterate on every 5 element and build my object at each time.

Thanks in advance.

My code :

```
 for (int i=0;i<I don't know what to put;i=i+5)
 {
    var o=new MyObject(list[i],list[i+1],list[i+2],list[i+3],list[i+4]);
    myObjects.Add(o);
 }
```

Comment: Iterating index of your elements incrementing `5`? Or maybe `Skip(5)`?

Comment: user469104, I add what I have tried.

Comment: you can use an if(i % 5 == 0)  condition to enter every 5 iterations

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
var list  = new List<MyObject>{ ... };
var list2 = new List<MyObject>();

for( int i = 0; i + 5 <= list.Count; i+=5 )
{
    list2.Add(new MyObject(list[i], list[i + 1], list[i + 2], list[i + 3], list[i + 4]));
}
```

or maybe this approach which takes incomplete groups into account:

```
for( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i+=5 )
{
    list2.Add(new MyObject(
        list[i], 
        list.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1),
        list.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 2),
        list.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 3), 
        list.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 4)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your list and resulting object to be something likethis:-

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
List<string> myObjects = new List<string>();
```

You can use LINQ:-

```
numbers.Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i / 5 })
                                .GroupBy(x => x.Index).ToList()
                                .ForEach(x => myObjects.Add(String.Join(",", x.Select(z => z.Value))));
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4lmRqS).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Skip` and `Taks`

```
int count = 0;
while(count < originalList.Count / 5)
{
    var list = originalList.Skip(count * 5).Take(5);
    //now you have 5 elements in list, and with them you can operate.
    //please be aware to check if list has 5 elements.

    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you do:

```
List<MyObject> results = new List<MyObject>();

for (int i = 5; i < list.Count; i += 5) {
   results.Add(new MyObject(list[i-5], list[i-4], list[i-3], list[i-2], list[i-1]));
}

// results  now contains your objects
```

Your question is very unclear. I dont know how you want to handle arrays lengths that arent divisible by 5 (e..g if you have 12 elements), what you are looking to return, whether its a list of objects or something else.

Thanks